# SMTP Authentication Support address/from name overwritten by Site Information

Tags: emails

Pretty much as the title says really. I'm using the SMTP Authentication Support module to try and send account notification e-mails through our G Suite account. I've filled in a name and e-mail address in the E-mail Options section, but whenever I send a test mail it arrives from the e-mail address given in Drupal's main Site Information options, and without a from name at all.

How do I get it to display a from name in the e-mails it sends?

Using Drupal 7.67 and SMTP Authentication 7.x-1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that you can't actually send a test though the module without turning the module on for everything. That was the problem. The test e-mail still gets sent if the module is turned off, and arrives with a message saying it was sent through SMTP, but on inspection of the headers it's clear it came through Drupal's regular mail system.

It would be nice if the test system would work independently of everything else, so you could establish if it works before turning it on for everything. Or if there was some warning that the test won't be sent via SMTP if the module's not turned on. But apparently that's not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module to configure how to send different emails.